# Multiple lines in shopping cart for same product with different options

Tags: php, session

I have a shopping cart system built that has multiple options for each item available. When the customer adds the items to the shopping cart, It save the selected options to that specific ID and displays it in the cart.

My code for doing so is as follows:

```
$optionsSelected = array();
 if(!empty($_POST['productOption'])){
    foreach($_POST['productOption'] as $options){
        $optionsSelected[] = $options;
    }
 }

case "add":
```

The $optionsSelected array var_dumps() as:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(21) "Swedish Fish Assorted" [1]=> string(31) "Beary Blue Rasberry Gummi Bears" [2]=> string(25) "Nonpareils Milk Chocolate" }

    $_SESSION['cart'][$productID]++;
    $_SESSION['options'.$productID] = $optionsSelected;

    header('location: /shop/cart');

break;
```

To display the options in the shopping cart I have:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['options'.$id] > 0): ?>
   <?php foreach($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $option): ?>
      <p><?php echo $option; ?></p>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now the only problem is the following:

Customer Adds `Product ID 4521` with options `A,C,and D` to the shopping cart, it displays nicely and works just fine.

Now the customer Adds the same `Product ID 4521` with options `D, B, and A` to the shopping cart, it displays the same product in the shopping cart with a quantity of 2 and now the options display `D, B, and A` and the first set of options are gone.

I need it to actually break those into different rows with a quantity of `1` for each.

```
Product Description     Options    Quantity

Product ID 4521         A, C, D       1 

Product ID 4521         D, B, A       1
```

I'm really not sure how to tell it to break these up and place them in the shopping cart as `individual items` since they have the same product ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a product in your array, you erase the old one with the new one.

You could use an alternative, for example a sub-array for each product

```
$optionsSelected = array();
if (!empty($_POST['productOption']))
{
   foreach ($_POST['productOption'] as $options)
      $optionsSelected[] = $options;
}

case "add": 
    $_SESSION['cart'][$productID]++;
    $_SESSION['options'.$productID][] = $optionsSelected; // line changed here

    header('location: /shop/cart');
break;
```

And then, you can display results this way

```
<?php if (count($_SESSION['options'.$id]) > 0): ?>
   <?php foreach($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $key => $options): ?>
      <?php echo '<p>Product ID '.$id.': '.implode(", ", $options).' (Quantity: '.$_SESSION['cart'][$id].')</p>'; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note: the display part could (should) look like this

```
<?php
if (count($_SESSION['options'.$id]) > 0)
{
   foreach ($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $key => $options)
   {
      echo '<p>Product ID '.$id.': '.implode(", ", $options).' (Quantity: '.$_SESSION['cart'][$id].')</p>';
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: I get this: `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in`

Comment: Well, that got it to display both sets of options. But I really wanted it to display on separate lines. Each with a separate quantity and option list.

Comment: Close enough I suppose.

Comment: This is what I have: `http://i1309.photobucket.com/albums/s627/mievan123/Capture_zpsab2fe131.png` What I am really wanting is completely separate line for each item that has different options.

Comment: Well that's up to you. I answered to your main question, now you can find an alternative for what you want

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use the following if you change your code a bit:

```
$array = array();

$array['options4521'][] = array('A','C','D');
$array['options4521'][] = array('B','B','A');

echo print_r($array);
```

And the output is:

```
[options4521] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => A
                [1] => C
                [2] => D
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => B
                [1] => B
                [2] => A
            )

    )
```